# Parsing quotes in R: Quantmod application

Tags: r, quotes, quantmod, volatility

I'm trying to create function that provides historical volatility after getting symbol from Yahoo. However, when I pass output to volatility function it doesn't like it; The Get variable gets assigned a vector with quotes, e.g. "SPY", but the volatility function only takes without quotes (SPY no "SPY"). I try to take quotes off using noquote() and now get following error:

Error in log(x) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

My code

```
require(quantmod)

vClose = function(X){
Get <- getSymbols(X, from="2000-01-01", src="yahoo")
Set <- noquote(Get)
volatility(Set, calc="close")
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `auto.assign=FALSE` in your call to `getSymbols`:

```
require(quantmod)
Get <- getSymbols("SPY", from="2000-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)
volatility(Get, calc="close")
```

Answer (score 2):

`noquote()`is not the answer.  Instead you want `get()`.  The following example works, though you might want to change the variable names as `get`and `Get`can get confused.

```
require(quantmod)

vClose = function(X){
Get <- getSymbols(X, from="2000-01-01", src="yahoo")
volatility(get(Get), calc="close")
}

vClose("SPY")
```